# Smartsheet API - how to populate excel data to specific fields in a smartsheet

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'd like to extract data from excel and copy to specific fields in a smartsheet. And I'm Novice in Smartsheet API. I'd like to know how it works between Excel and Smartsheet.

Answer (score 2):

The Smartsheet API uses widely accepted standards, including REST for access, JSON format for the data.

To get started, I'd suggest taking a look at our [API documentation](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/). We have code samples available in a number of languages. As far as Excel is concerned, we don't currently offer support for extracting data from Excel. However, our documentation should cover extracting/inputting data into Smartsheet.

If you have any questions on our API, you can also reach out to api@smartsheet.com with any questions.